# Single dash in CSS? What does it mean?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am seeing a single dash in the Chrome developer tools as seen in the image below.

[image]

What does this refer to? If it had a digit associated with it I would think it meant negative.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing.

That's not a valid value for this (or any) CSS property, it looks like whatever generated that style either failed to provide a value or it's inserting invalid values on purpose (whatever that might be)...

Inspect the element and on the Styles tab (on Chrome) if the property value is invalid it'll show with a yellow explanation mark.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Whomever wrote that code just didn't know what they were doing. They declare `padding-right` 3 times in one style attribute, and all of them are invalid values (including the one that just says `-2` with no units. If we go to chrome dev tools and we apply that same property/value to an element, we get this:

[image]

when you hover on the yellow triangle, it tells you that the `-` is an "Invalid property value".

Comment: 3 paddings-right and one margin-right ;) but agreed, the library is doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo. Fixed.